# Only adding integers to session array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have problem where I am using AJAX + PHP to insert product id to `$SESSION['korpica'] = array();` Everything is working for id where i have only numbers(222,223,440,900,911) but when it comes to (**A320M BAZOOKA**, **A320M GAMING PRO**, **A320M PRO-VH PLUS**) it is not working.
I searched but nothing helped me. Here is my code .

**Declaring array in index.php**

```
session_start();
$korpa = array();
$_SESSION['korpica'] = $korpa;
```

**button**

```
<button type="button" class="addToCart btn-button" title="Dodaj u korpu" onclick="dodaj('<?php echo $sifra; ?>');">  <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
<span>Add to Cart</span>   
</button>
```

**dodaj.js**

```
function dodaj(sifra) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dodajUKorpu.php',
        type: "GET",
        data: {'korpas':sifra}


    });
}
```

**dodajUKorpu.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['korpas']) && $_GET['korpas']!=0){
    array_push($_SESSION['korpica'], $_GET['korpas']);
}

?>
```

**Working for** id -> 222, 223, 444, 900, 121, 911

**Not working for** id -> A320M BAZOOKA, A320M GAMING PRO, A320M PRO-VH PLUS, A68HM-P33 V1, AD5150JAHMBOX

Comment: $_GET['korpas']!=0

You are checking for numbers only. So, for string it will always be false.

Comment: @HarshadShettigar I really spent 4 hours for this..... Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)